# mingw makefile add cpp folder

Tags: makefile, mingw

This is my makefile.

```
FLAGS = -W -Wall -std=c++11
FILES = Main.cpp Vector.cpp

OBJS = $(FILES:%.cpp=%.o)

all: $(OBJS)
    g++ $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

%.o: %.cpp
g++ -c $< -o $@ $(FLAGS)
```

Lets say Main.cpp is in the main folder and Vector.cpp is in a "brother" folder ( A common folder for exemple ), is it possible to make this compile by just adding an argument to FLAGS? Something like -I but for cpp files not header ( or something that will works for both ).

Thanks

Comment: See [4.5 Searching Directories for Prerequisites](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Directory-Search) in the GNU Make manual. That might do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GNU Make feature of "vpath" is probably what you are looking for here.

See section [4.5 Searching Directories for Prerequisites](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Directory-Search) in the manual for more information about setting this up.